# Breeze: complex graph returns only 1 collection

Tags: nosql, breeze

I have a physician graph that looks something like this:

[image: Physician Graph]

The query I use to get data from a WebApi backend looks like this:

```
      var query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from("Physicians")
    .expand("ContactInfo")
    .expand("ContactInfo.Phones")
    .expand("ContactInfo.Addresses")
    .expand("PhysicianNotes")
    .expand("PhysicianSpecialties")
    .where("ContactInfo.LastName", "startsWith", lastInitial).take(5);
```

(note the ContactInfo is a pseudonym of the People object)

What I find is that If I request Contact.Phones to be expanded, I'll get just phones and no Notes or Specialties.  If I comment out the phones I'll get Contact.Addresses and no other collections.  If I comment out ContactInfo along with Phones and Addresses I'll get Notes only etc.  Essentially, it seems like I can only get one collection at a time.

So, Is this a built in 'don't let the programmer shoot himself in the foot'?? safeguard or do I have to enable something?

OR is this graph too complicated??  should I consider a NoSql object store??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all your expand clauses in a single one like this:

```
var query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from("Physicians")
    .expand("ContactInfo, ContactInfo.Phones, ContactInfo.Addresses, PhysicianNotes, PhysicianSpecialties")
    .where("ContactInfo.LastName", "startsWith", lastInitial).take(5);
```

You can see the documentation here: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_expand

Answer (score 1):

JY told you *HOW*. But *BEWARE* of performance consequences ... both on the data tier and over the wire. You can die a miserable death by grabbing too widely and deeply at once.

I saw the `take(5)` in his sample. That is crucial for restraining a runaway request (something you really must do also on the server). In general, I would reserve extended graph fetches of this kind for queries that pulled a single root entity.  If I'm presenting a list for selection and I need data from different parts of the entity graph, I'd use a projection to get exactly what I need to display (assuming, of course, that there is no SQL View readily available for this purpose).

If any of the related items are reference lists (color, status, states, ...), consider bringing them into cache separately in a preparation step. Don't include them in the `expand`; Breeze will connect them on the client to your queried entities automatically.

Finally, as a matter of syntax, you don't have to repeat the name of a segment. When you write "ContactInfo.Phones", you get both ContactInfos and Phones so you don't need to specify "ContactInfo" by itself.

Comment: Yes, thanks Ward.  I understand what you're saying.  I'm doing some proof-of-concept things here.  In a real app, I'd be doing as you suggest with the list DTO.  Thanks for the heads up on the .expand